# How to show all the Users who have liked my specific Items

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I apologize for the newbie questions still relatively new to rails. I'm trying to show all the users who have liked a current user's specific items. With the help of the SO community and looking at different Rails guides - I'm 85% there. Currently, I'm displaying all users who have liked all items (not just my specific ones which is what I want) I've listed below all the relevant simple code - thank you so much guys!!

**Index.html.erb**

```
<%- @likers.each do |liker| %>
<%= image_tag liker.avatar, width: 25, class: "css-style" %>&nbsp
<%= liker.username %>
<% end %>
```

**Items_controller**

```
def index
@items = Item.order("created_at DESC") 
if current_user.present? 
@likers = Item.where("user_id", current_user.id).map(&:users).flatten
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want all `@likers` to be all the people who like the `current_user`'s `items`?

```
@likers = current_user.items.map(&:likes).flatten.map(&:user).flatten.uniq
```

I've added the `uniq` so if a user likes more than one of these posts, you won't see them turn up multiple times. You can omit that, of course, if you want duplicates.

I'm also making some guesses about your other models based on your previous question, so you might need to tweak it depending on your actual implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This works amazing - i just had to change (&:users) to (&:user)

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me out for one minute with this question whenever you might be free - I'm super close to the answer but just been stuck on it forever. If you can help me out would be amazing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325401/how-to-count-all-the-likes-that-user-has-done-on-my-specific-items-rails