# How to count all the likes that User has done on my specific items (Rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

My apologies for the newbie question, I'm relatively new to Rails and SQL. I'm trying to count all the likes a User has done on my specific items. With the help of the SO community and from Treehouse Coding I am able to show which Users have liked my specific items. In addition, I was able to research how to show all the likes that I have received (from Lisa, James, Harry, etc.) using .join in my controller. Now I would like to show the count for each specific User. So for instance if James like 4 of my items I would like to show 4 next to James. I have listed all my relevant code below, thank you guys so much!!

**Index.html.erb**

```
My Fans - <%= @likersnumero%>
<%- @likers.each do |liker| %>
<%= image_tag liker.avatar, width: 25, class: "css-style"  %>
<%= liker.username %>
<% end %>
```

**Items_controller**

```
def index
@items = Item.order("created_at DESC")
if current_user.present? 
@likers = current_user.items.map(&:likes).flatten.map(&:user).flatten
@likersnumero = current_user.items.joins(:likes).map(&:user).count
end
end
```

**Item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
has_many :likes, :counter_cache => true
end
```

**Users.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :likes
def likes?(post)
    post.likes.where(user_id: id).any?
end

#Tried using def total_likes in my index.html.erb using <%= liker.total_likes%>
but got the following
 error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: likes:
 SELECT SUM(likes) FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."user_id" = ?"
def total_likes
    likes.sum(:likes)   
end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :items do
resource :like, module: :items
end
root to: "items#index"
end
```

**Schema.rb**

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "product"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "item_id"
t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
t.string   "avatar_file_name"
t.string   "avatar_content_type"
t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
t.integer  "likes_count",         default: 0, null: false
end

create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "item_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless reading and experiementing I figured out the answer that worked for me. In case anyone might encounter a similar issue - I have provided the answer that worked for me.

To get total likes **by a specific user on all users items** - In my controller I put the following 
    @likersuno = @likers.map(&:likes).flatten.map(&:user).flatten.uniq

And in my index.html.erb

I simply put this and it worked from there

```
<%= @likersuno.count %>
```

To get total likes **by a specific user on my specific items** - In my index.html.erb I put the following and it worked beautifully

```
<%= liker.likes.select { |like| like.item.user == current_user }.count %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `liker` is the  user who liked post and `poster_id` is the id of the person who create the post.

```
liker.likes.joins(:items).where('items.user_id = ?', poster_id).count
```

Or somethings similar. If you post your [annotated](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) model or table schema I can probably come up with a better answer.

Comment: Antar thank you so much for responding. I put your code and got an error stating undefined method `likes' for #<Array:0x007ff8083f96e0>

Comment: @Omar Have you seen my update answer? I've update it a few times. Can you post the full code you inserted? I looks like the item you are operating of is an `Array` and not a `User` object.

Comment: Antarr i did the only modification that i did in my controller was set @liker.likes

Comment: Once you call map @likers becomes an array and not an ActiveRecord object. I will post an update soon.

Comment: @Omar Try setting `@likers` this way. `@likers = current_user.likes.include(:items).select('items.user')`, not sure if it works since I don't have a valid codebase to work against!

Comment: Antarr, thank you so much for your response. I just added my routes file to the question not sure if that was what you were asking for.